# Cant login to mysql new user?

Tags: mysql, root

I've **recently** downloaded and started using mysql. I've set it up hopefully correct and my **root user also logs in.** The **mysql service is also running.**

I ran the **following lines to create a datbase and new user**, but I could not log in to my new user. Please help. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I've searched for a solution online but get confused as to what is the right steps to follow.

***Thank you*** :)

```
PS C:\Users\Akhil> mysql -u root -p;
Enter password: *****

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 24
Server version: 5.6.41-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| mytestdb           |
| performance_schema |
| sakila             |
| test               |
| world              |
+--------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> use mytestdb
Database changed

mysql> create user myuser identified by 'mypass';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'myuser'@'%'

mysql> DROP USER myuser;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> create user myuser identified by 'mypass';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mytestdb.* TO myuser;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye
PS C:\Users\Akhil> mysql -u myuser -p
Enter password: ******
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

PS C:\Users\Akhil>
```

**Why am I getting access denied is beyond me...Help?**

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the error. What I did was **Login with root user**. Then type the following command:-

`DROP USER ''@localhost ;`

***then it worked like a charm!***